# Cant import data due to illegal double

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am having a very annoying problem trying to import a wordpress db backup I am using wootickets to sell tickets for an event and for a customers db its complaing on xampp that their is a a illegal double here in the insert into statement shown below.  Their hudreds of these values scattered thruought the the file i  persume used for security.

> INSERT INTO `fl_postmeta` (  `meta_id` , `post_id` , `meta_key` , `meta_value`  ) VALUES ( 165743, 3313, '_tribe_wooticket_security_code', 'e801d16bb2' );

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1367 - Illegal double '342e880385' value found during parsing

My Question is why would this be the case when i exported from a linux platform to xamp for testing how do i fix this

Comment: Is the system you are importing onto a 32bit OS?

Answer (score 1):

The value `342e880385` should be put inside single quotes, like so:

```
INSERT INTO fl_postmeta ( meta_id , post_id , meta_key , meta_value )
VALUES ( 162936, 3115, '_tribe_wooticket_security_code', '342e880385' );
```

Otherwise, MySQL will try to parse it as a number.

Comment: it is in in quotes in the file sorry markdown must have done that